# Why is this generator pipeline slower than a traditional loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a traditional loop and converted it into a pipeline of generator functions, and then compared the speed using timeit. To my surprise I found that the generator pipeline is about 25% slower than the  traditional loop. I'm curious as to why the generator pipeline is slower.

Here is the traditional loop:

```
def process(numbers):
    results = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number < 0:
            continue
        if number % 2 != 0:
            continue
        multiplication = number * 3
        results.append(multiplication)
    return results
```

Here is the same loop broken down into a series of generator functions:

```
def positive(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        if number >= 0:
            yield number


def even(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            yield number


def multiply(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        yield number * 3


def process2(numbers):
    return list(multiply(even(positive(numbers))))
```

They both have the same result:

```
assert process(range(1000000)) == process2(range(1000000))
```

However, the traditional loop is about 1/4th faster than the generator pipeline:

```
import timeit

# Traditional:
setup = 'from __main__ import process'
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='process(range(1000000))', setup=setup, number=100))
# 12.314972606060678

# Generator pipeline
setup2 = 'from __main__ import process2'
print(timeit.timeit(stmt='process2(range(1000000))', setup=setup2, number=100))
# 16.349763878787826
```

I would have expected these two to have roughly similar speeds.

What is it about the generator pipeline that leads to the reduction in speed?

Comment: You're applying the conditions in the reverse order.  How does that affect the number of tests performed?

Comment: Why would you think that generator's are faster? They are more memory efficient (they only generate data as needed instead of all at once). They still process the same python code as a non-generator.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I corrected the order (and edited my post) but the performance is still similar.

Comment: @BobbyOcean I would have thought that the two styles would have been equivalent.

Comment: Suspending and resuming a bunch of generators has overhead.

Comment: Do you want a more performant solution to this problem or is this just an example??

Comment: Well, I am surprised at the detectable difference. But at the same time, function compiling, calls, transfer of variables, and conditionals all have a lot of overhead. I should point out that in your generators you have separate functions and separate conditionals, hence they all compiled separately.

Comment: Wait, i just noticed that you iterator over the list 3 times in one and only once in the other. You have 3 for loops to 1 for loop.

Comment: @BobbyOcean Isn't that the nature of breaking up a traditional loop into a series of generators? I was under the impression that even though it looks like you have three loops using the generator style, behind the scenes it was essentially a single loop.

Comment: also `[x * 3 for x in numbers if x >= 0 and x % 2 == 0]` will be faster than both by a fair margin. (106 ms += 1 vs 128 and 195 respectively)

Comment: @modesitt this is just an example to demonstrate a difference. My real use case is the desire to break down a large traditional loop with many conditions into a pipeline of generator functions.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Ya, scratch what I said.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to make claims about generators being *faster* but that do give a concurrent model of computation where calling `process2` without the `list` constructor will be *instantish*. So your program can continue and use the resulting `numbers` once - if it has to. The generator aids in speed when its results may or may not be used down the line depending on other conditions. There is overhead in executing the nested procedures over a changing iterable. Any speed difference will be use-case and interpreter specific. If you want speed for numeric computation, use numpy ;)

Comment: @modesitt I originally expected the generator to be equivalent to the traditional loop in terms of speed. I'm actually interested in using the generator pipeline only to improve the clarity of the code- using generators can reduce the number of lines of code and can otherwise improve readability. I was surprised to see that there was a degradation of performance, however.

Comment: Using several *functions* like this can degrade performance in general, generally speaking, "inlining" code is significantly faster. Generators have even more additional overhead than a regular function, so this is about what you'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why something is slower or faster, always pull out the profiler. Python comes with a few:

```
import cProfile

>>> cProfile.run('process(range(900000))')
         450004 function calls in 0.171 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.135    0.135    0.165    0.165 <stdin>:1(process)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.171    0.171 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.171    0.171 {built-in method builtins.exec}
   450000    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


>>> cProfile.run('process2(range(900000))')
         1800007 function calls in 0.356 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   450001    0.140    0.000    0.238    0.000 <stdin>:1(even)
   900001    0.098    0.000    0.098    0.000 <stdin>:1(multiply)
   450001    0.072    0.000    0.310    0.000 <stdin>:1(positive)
        1    0.040    0.040    0.351    0.351 <stdin>:1(process2)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.356    0.356 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.356    0.356 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Notice that it seems as though the function `multiply` is called once per item in the list. At first I thought this was absurd, but when you think about how generators work - it makes sense. When you `yield`, the context has to pause, and later when execution continues - it's as though you re-enter that function's context. It would make sense that the profiler counts this as an invocation of the function. You can see how much time each function is using in the `tottime` column.

So in the end - the answer is similar to what you got in the comments - generators and the `yield` keyword take more time than equivalent but purely procedural code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding a pile of overhead to stop and resume those generators. Generators are pretty efficient (the fact that starting and stopping them that many times only costs you 50ms is pretty amazing to me), but they're a fundamental tradeoff between CPU and RAM. Give up a few CPU cycles for the overhead, and in return, only one value is ever in memory at a given moment. Unless allocating memory for very large objects or something equivalent is dominating your CPU usage, you'll generally not gain runtime performance by using generators instead of lists/loops.

However, as @modesitt points out in their comment, using a list comprehension is going to be faster than all of the examples above, since the case you demonstrate is so simple. If you want the end results all stored in memory anyway, consider using list comprehensions instead of generator comprehensions. You'll gain the minor performance advantages of comprehensions without requiring the extra overhead of generators.